# Bibliografia en latex

Tags: latex

Estoy utilizando biblatex, uso \printbibliography y al compilar el titulo es "Referencias" pero necesito que sea "Bibliografia", de pronto sea muy tonto mi problema, pero no encuentro respuesta.
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes renombrar el comando

```
\printbibliography[title={Bibliografia}]
```